# CI Controller not getting loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I have a site using CI version 2.1.3 running on a xampp install locally. The code has been put in a git repository.
I cloned the code into a directory on another machine (also running xammp install with identical paths).

Now on the 'other machine' it refuses to load the CI_Controoler class, giving the error message;

```
Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\dev\www\my_site\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 244
```

I have added some code to system/core/Codeigniter to check what is going on. This is...

```
// Load the base controller class
require BASEPATH.'core/Controller.php';

function &get_instance()
{
        if (file_exists(BASEPATH.'core/Controller.php')) {
            echo 'file exists<br />';
            if (class_exists('CI_Controller')) {
                echo 'class exists<br />';
            } else {
                echo 'no class<br />';
            }
        } else {
            echo 'no file found<br />';
        }

    return CI_Controller::get_instance();
}
```

The resulting output is...

```
file exists
no class

Fatal error: Class 'CI_Controller' not found in C:\dev\www\my_site\system\core\CodeIgniter.php on line 244
```

So it is finding the class, but not loading it, any ideas why??

Comment: This may sound dumb, but just for covering the basics, did you check the contents for the Controller.php file? Maybe it got corrupted or emptied for strange reason?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As usual, fault is with sleepy developer!
I enabled full logging in config and found out it was throwing an error regarding the database class; which was due to me having a typo in the database config file.

Changed it and now all is fine.